# JTable hides the header after INSERT

Tags: java, mysql, swing

So I'm just starting making a sample project where can I insert my Employee and Department connected to database. When I trying to insert some values on my fields. The header or columns hides after hitting the button "add". Any help would appreciate!

**CODES**

```
   String inputEmployee = employeeTf.getText();
   String inputDepartment = departmentTf.getText();

   if(inputEmployee.isEmpty() && inputDepartment.isEmpty()){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill up!");
    }
    else if(inputEmployee.isEmpty()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Employee Name should not be left blank");
    }
    else if(inputDepartment.isEmpty()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Department should not be left blank");
    }
    else{
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        jTable.setModel(model);
        Object[] row = new Object[2];

        String myQuery = "INSERT INTO SAMPLE (EMPLOYEENAME,DEPARTMENT) VALUES (?,?)";

        try{
            Connection myCon = DBUtilities.getConnection(DBType.JDBC);
            PreparedStatement myPs = myCon.prepareStatement(myQuery);

            myPs.setString(1, employeeTf.getText());
            myPs.setString(2, departmentTf.getText());

            row[0] = employeeTf.getText();
            row[1] = departmentTf.getText();

            myPs.executeUpdate();

            System.out.print("Record is inserted");


        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            DBUtilities.processException(ex);
       }     
        finally {
        try {
           if(myPs != null) myPs.close();
           if(myCon != null) myCon.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error is: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

[image]

When I try to insert John in Employee fields and BSIT in Department fields. The header disappear.

[image]

As you can see here the header/columns disappear. What did I missed? Thanks

Comment: When you update from the database, you create a new `DefaultTableModel`, but you never add any columns to the model

Comment: @MadProgrammer do I need to make an object for my columns like this? Object[] columns = {"Name","Department"};
I drag and drop this components do I need to call the columns?

Comment: Have a read of the [JavaDocs for `DefaultTableModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html), but basically yes

Comment: `do I need to make an object for my columns like this?` - no because your TableModel already contains the column names or they wouldn't display in the table. You just need to update the existing TableModel instead of creating a new TableModel.

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks It already working but Its not loading to database?

Comment: You don't add any rows to the new instance of `TableModel`

Comment: @MadProgrammer sorry for annoying you. But how will I do that? Im just a little bit confused. I'm just new learning java. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, reading the comment wrong it's not inserting into the database? Have commited the transaction

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes its not inserting into a database. My values is already loading to my Tables but in the database its not. Did I missed something? Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Check the return result of `myPs.executeUpdate();`, it should return the number of rows which were affected by the call (should be `1`). You may also need to call `Connection#commit` after it, as `autoCommit` may be turned off

Answer (score 1):

```
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    jTable.setModel(model);
```

You create a new TableModel without any columns. Don't create a new TableModel.

Instead just use the current TableModel from the JTable (since it already contains the column names) to add new rows of data:

```
//DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
//jTable.setModel(model);
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)tTable.getModel();
```

Then when you update your database with the data you can update the table at the same time.

```
myPs.executeUpdate();
model.addRow( row );
```

Of course this assumes you actually created the JTable using a DefaultTableModel in the first place.

Comment: Thanks! You got my problem bro. I have a question what will I add on my parameter.
model.add(row); // What will I put in my parameter?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Did you read the `DefaultTableModel` API??? The `addRow(...)` method needs a Vector or an Array as a parameter. You already have a the row variable defined as an Array and you add two values to the Array. So why wouldn't you use that?

Comment: Thanks bro its already working. I just add model.addRow(new Object[]{employeeTf.getText(),departmentTf.getText()});. But its not loading to database? Thanks again

Comment: Why are you creating a new Object array? I just stated your already have a "row" variable that is an Object Array. A JTable has nothing to do with the database. That is an SQL problem. This question has been answered so the question should be closed.